# Cannot find module './models/config'

Tags: angular2-cli

Updating my Angular 2 CLI project from `1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.2` to `1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.8` [according to instructions](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/WEBPACK_UPDATE.md):

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g angular-cli@webpack
```

resulted in this:

```
jan@linux-zd16:~/src/fm-repos/fm-ui> ng --version
Cannot find module './models/config'
Error: Cannot find module './models/config'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:455:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:403:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jan/src/fm-repos/fm-ui/node_modules/angular-cli/addon/ng2/index.js:4:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When installing Angular CLI, explicitly use the latest version, instead:

## Update global Angular CLI

```
rm -rf node_modules dist tmp
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g angular-cli@latest
```

## Update project's Angular CLI

```
npm install --save-dev angular-cli@latest
```

## Update project's configuration files

```
ng init
```

and carefully review each difference.

Comment: I am having the same issue as you, but only get it to work with webpack.8 as well. Were you able to upgrade to beta 15?

Comment: yes, @cport1 -- I successfully upgraded to `beta.15`.

Comment: What did you have to do to get it to work with beta.15?

Comment: @cport1 - see my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39600939/invalid-configuration-object-webpack-has-been-initialised-using-a-configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Angular 2 has very recently changed it's build engine from SystemJS to Webpack in it's latest release. Which could be one (amongst other) reasons for this error message (it was for me anyway).

If you want to ensure you use the latest, like discussed on [their git page](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/Upgrading-from-Beta.10-to-Beta.14), you can run:

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g angular-cli@latest //in theory, npm install -g angular-cli should be OK
```

Now your project is likely still 'setup' to use the previous build system, so it's easier to delete your node_modules, and reinstall:

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

You can verify the installation via:

```
ng build
```