# Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration

Tags: angular, angular2-cli

As of this morning, with Angular CLI `1.0.0-beta.14` I `ng new try3` and `ng serve` and get the following error:

```
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration has an unknown property 'tslint'. These properties are valid:
   object { amd?, bail?, cache?, context?, devServer?, devtool?, entry, externals?, loader?, module?, name?, dependencies?, node?, output?, plugins?, profile?, recordsInputPath?, recordsOutputPath?, recordsPath?, resolve?, resolveLoader?, stats?, target?, watch?, watchOptions? }
 - configuration.module has an unknown property 'preLoaders'. These properties are valid:
   object { rules?, loaders?, noParse?, unknownContextRequest?, unknownContextRegExp?, unknownContextRecursive?, unknownContextCritical?, exprContextRequest?, exprContextRegExp?, exprContextRecursive?, exprContextCritical?, wrappedContextRegExp?, wrappedContextRecursive?, wrappedContextCritical? }
   Options affecting the normal modules (`NormalModuleFactory`).
 - configuration.node.global should be a boolean.
 - configuration.resolve has an unknown property 'root'. These properties are valid:
   object { modules?, descriptionFiles?, plugins?, mainFields?, aliasFields?, mainFiles?, extensions?, enforceExtension?, moduleExtensions?, enforceModuleExtension?, alias?, symlinks?, unsafeCache?, cachePredicate?, fileSystem?, resolver? }
 - configuration.resolve.extensions[0] should not be empty.
WebpackOptionsValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration has an unknown property 'tslint'. These properties are valid:
   object { amd?, bail?, cache?, context?, devServer?, devtool?, entry, externals?, loader?, module?, name?, dependencies?, node?, output?, plugins?, profile?, recordsInputPath?, recordsOutputPath?, recordsPath?, resolve?, resolveLoader?, stats?, target?, watch?, watchOptions? }
 - configuration.module has an unknown property 'preLoaders'. These properties are valid:
   object { rules?, loaders?, noParse?, unknownContextRequest?, unknownContextRegExp?, unknownContextRecursive?, unknownContextCritical?, exprContextRequest?, exprContextRegExp?, exprContextRecursive?, exprContextCritical?, wrappedContextRegExp?, wrappedContextRecursive?, wrappedContextCritical? }
   Options affecting the normal modules (`NormalModuleFactory`).
 - configuration.node.global should be a boolean.
 - configuration.resolve has an unknown property 'root'. These properties are valid:
   object { modules?, descriptionFiles?, plugins?, mainFields?, aliasFields?, mainFiles?, extensions?, enforceExtension?, moduleExtensions?, enforceModuleExtension?, alias?, symlinks?, unsafeCache?, cachePredicate?, fileSystem?, resolver? }
 - configuration.resolve.extensions[0] should not be empty.
    at webpack (/home/jan/src/fm-repos/try3/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:16:9)
    at Class.run (/home/jan/src/fm-repos/try3/node_modules/angular-cli/tasks/serve-webpack.js:23:27)
    at /home/jan/src/fm-repos/try3/node_modules/angular-cli/commands/serve.js:84:26
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
```

The last time I `ng new` a project was a few days ago -- at that point it worked file. Here's my environment:

```
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.14
node: 6.5.0
os: linux x64
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Upgrade Angular CLI to `1.0.0-beta.15` or better:

```
  npm uninstall angular-cli -g
  npm cache clean
  npm install angular-cli@latest -g
```

which generates working scaffolds:

```
  ng new try4
  cd try4
  ng serve
```

If you have an existing project built with prior versions of Angular CLI, you will need to upgrade:

```
  rm -rf node_modules dist tmp
  npm install angular-cli@latest --save-dev
  ng init
```

and carefully review each of the differences in each file.

**Root cause**: Once a version of Angular CLI is working, it should **not** stop working, of course. Unfortunately, `angular-cli 1.0.0-beta.14` has a *"caret" dependency* on `webpack: ^2.1.0-beta.22` -- note the `^`. Yesterday, `webpack` released `2.1.0-beta.23` which is not compatible with `angular-cli 1.0.0-beta.14` so, due to the caret (`^`), deployed versions of `angular-cli 1.0.0-beta.14` have stopped working. To address this problem, `angular-cli 1.0.0-beta.15` was released yesterday with a *fixed* `webpack: 2.1.0-beta.22` dependency -- note the **lack of the `^`** -- thus avoiding the breaking upgrade to webpack. See https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2234 for details.

**Project work-around**: If you can't, or won't, upgrade Angular CLI, you can work-around the *caret webpack dependency* by adding a *fixed webpack dependency* to your own project. You'll have to maintain this dependency going forward, of course:

```
  npm install webpack@2.1.0-beta.22 --save-dev
```

Choose this work-around if you can't upgrade Angular CLI.

Comment: For whatever reason it kept installing `1.0.0-beta.14` for me and I had to do `npm install -g angular/angular-cli` (install directly from GitHub repo) in order to get `1.0.0-beta.15`.

Comment: I follow this, install version beta.15, rm node_modules on my project, etc etc `ng init` get: Cannot find module '@angular/core'

Comment: @AderbalNunes -- see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39780833/error-cannot-find-module-angular-core

Answer (score 19):

I just ran into this issue today running an ng2.0.0 project
the solution was to downgrade webpack.

```
npm uninstall webpack --save-dev

npm install webpack@2.1.0-beta.22 --save-dev
```

this will probably be fixed soon on the package.json that `angular-cli 1.0.0-beta.15` generates.

this fix should resolve the issue on any existing projects.

Comment: Angular CLI `1.0.0-beta.15` was released yesterday to address this, as I noted in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using webpack2 beta?

If yes you can't have custom properties in configuration now.

you need to add your custom properties via plugins:

```
plugins: {
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      options: {
        postcss: ...
      }
    })
}
```

Comment: `angular-cli 1.0.0-beta.15` has a dependency on `webpack: 2.1.0-beta.22` (whereas `angular-cli 1.0.0-beta.14` has a dependency on `webpack: ^2.1.0-beta.22`).

Comment: You're welcome, @Taspina -- I've updated my answer with the details of **why** it broke...

Comment: `plugins` should be an array, not object.

Answer (score 1):

npm uninstall webpack --save-dev

followed by

npm install webpack@2.1.0-beta.22 --save-dev

Then you should be able to gulp again. Fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try running these commands:

```
npm uninstall angular-cli -g
npm cache clean
npm install webpack // Move webpack to latest
```

Answer (score 0):

If angular-cli is not installed globally `npm install angular-cli@latest -g`

Check angular-cli is installed or not using this command `ng --version`

This fixes the issue in my case `npm install webpack`

Answer (score -1):

Please check whether the ts-loader is installed in your project. It is must and should for loading the .ts files.

Answer (score -1):

Also make sure your `loaders` object is under `module` e.g

```
  module: {
    loaders: [{test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader'}]
  }
```

This solved the issue for me