# Error: Cannot find module '@angular/core'

Tags: angular-cli

After updating my `@angular` `2.0.1` application's `angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.15` to `angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.16`, the `ng init` fails with:

```
Cannot find module '@angular/core'
Error: Cannot find module '@angular/core'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:455:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:403:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jan/src/fm-repos/fm-ui/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/plugin.js:4:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jan/src/fm-repos/fm-ui/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js:6:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jan/src/fm-repos/fm-ui/node_modules/angular-cli/models/webpack-build-typescript.js:5:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jan/src/fm-repos/fm-ui/node_modules/angular-cli/models/webpack-config.js:2:34)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jan/src/fm-repos/fm-ui/node_modules/angular-cli/tasks/build-webpack.js:6:24)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jan/src/fm-repos/fm-ui/node_modules/angular-cli/commands/build.js:3:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Class.includedCommands (/home/jan/src/fm-repos/fm-ui/node_modules/angular-cli/addon/index.js:20:16)
    at /home/jan/src/fm-repos/fm-ui/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/models/project.js:392:61
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Project.addonCommands (/home/jan/src/fm-repos/fm-ui/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/models/project.js:391:15)
    at Project.eachAddonCommand (/home/jan/src/fm-repos/fm-ui/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/models/project.js:426:30)
    at module.exports (/home/jan/src/fm-repos/fm-ui/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/cli/lookup-command.js:33:13)
    at CLI.<anonymous> (/home/jan/src/fm-repos/fm-ui/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/cli/cli.js:34:26)
    at tryCatch (/home/jan/src/fm-repos/fm-ui/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:538:12)
    at invokeCallback (/home/jan/src/fm-repos/fm-ui/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:553:13)
    at publish (/home/jan/src/fm-repos/fm-ui/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:521:7)
    at flush (/home/jan/src/fm-repos/fm-ui/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:2370:5)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

**Update procedure**:

```
ng --version
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.15
node: 6.5.0
os: linux x64

npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g angular-cli@latest
```

followed by in my project directory:

```
rm -rf node_modules dist tmp
npm install --save-dev angular-cli@latest
ng init                                         <-- failure here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrade the project's `@angular` from `2.0.1` to `2.0.0` by editing `package.json`, then:

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

Then `ng init` works, again; and then, you can upgrade to `@angular 2.0.1`.